# Error in dynamic sorting with linq

Tags: linq, sorting

I want to sort data in grid. I have multiple columns in grid and on click of grid header list should be sort by that particular column. I am using linq to sort data from db and my code as below:

```
var newsLetterData = _db.NewsLetterHistory.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(**sortExp**)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x)
    .ToList()
    .Skip(pageIndex)
    .Take(pageSize);

newsLetter = newsLetterData
    .Select(x => new NewsLetterHistory
    {
        NewsLetterHistoryId = x.NewsLetterHistoryId,
        Subject = x.Subject,
        Content = x.Content,
        TotalEmailSent = x.TotalEmailSent,
        Receivers = x.Receivers,
        CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
     })
     .Select(z => z)
     .ToList();
```

In above query I am using "sortby" expression to sort data and bellow I am creating this dynamic sort expression:

```
var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory),
                   typeof(TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory).ToString());

Expression propConvExp = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramExp, sortColumn), typeof(object));

var sortExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory, object>>(propConvExp, paramExp);
```

But as I am running my code I am getting error:

> "Unable to cast the type '`System.DateTime`' to type '`System.Object`'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Anybody have some idea how I can resolve this or how can I create dynamic sorting to sort data in linq?

Comment: without solving your problem here, you do know that all those  `.Select(x=>x)` are redundant and that the call to `.AsEnumerable` and `.ToList` are killing performance, since you don't allow SQL to handle the paging (you're doing that in memory in your application right now).

Comment: so I should remove .AsEnumerable? But .ToList is mandatory for me and I am getting only 10 records at a time.

Comment: The `ToList` at the end is fine. Just make sure you don't `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` before adding all your filter criteria such as `Where`, `OrderBy`, `Take`, `Skip` and `Select` etc. That fetches the whole recordset to the client and does the filtering client side.

Comment: In your case, with only 10 records, that shouldn't matter much, but it's a good practice to learn and apply always.

Comment: Thanks  jessehouwing to suggest this. Really helpful regarding performance. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do sorting here and modified my code to create dynamic sort expression as bellow:

```
Type newsLetterType = typeof(TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory);

List<NewsLetterHistory> newsLetter = null;
if (newsLetterType.GetProperties().Any(prop => prop.Name == sortColumn))
{
    PropertyInfo pinfo = newsLetterType.GetProperty(sortColumn);
    Func<TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory, object> orderByExpr = (news => pinfo.GetValue(news, null));
    Func<IEnumerable<TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory>,  IOrderedEnumerable<TemplateProject.DataAccess.NewsLetterHistory>> sortFunc = null;
}
```

Above code is working fine for me.